# Stack overflow while making EditText clickable

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext, stack-overflow

I try to make three EditTexts clickable with an onFocusChangeListener, but sometimes I get this:

```
03-02 11:57:06.340: E/InputEventReceiver(24904): Exception dispatching input event.
03-02 11:57:06.342: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904): java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.text.Layout.primaryIsTrailingPrevious(Layout.java:742)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:805)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:796)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5452)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocusInAbsoluteDirection(FocusFinder.java:232)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:163)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ScrollView.java:1454)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2622)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2622)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7594)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7573)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.rootViewRequestFocus(View.java:5082)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:5068)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.clearFocus(View.java:5045)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at com.example.stoos.NeuesSpiel$5.onFocusChange(NeuesSpiel.java:238)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:5182)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7897)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4938)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7648)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7627)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ScrollView.java:1467)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2622)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2622)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7594)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7573)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.rootViewRequestFocus(View.java:5082)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:5068)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.clearFocus(View.java:5045)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at com.example.stoos.NeuesSpiel$5.onFocusChange(NeuesSpiel.java:238)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:5182)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7897)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4938)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:7648)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:7627)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ScrollView.java:1467)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2622)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2663)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2619)
03-02 11:57:08.142: E/MessageQueue-JNI(24904):  at android.view.ViewGroup.
03-02 11:57:08.782: E/AndroidRuntime(24904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 11:57:08.782: E/AndroidRuntime(24904): Process: com.example.stoos,  PID: 24904
03-02 11:57:08.782: E/AndroidRuntime(24904): java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

I use this code:

```
buttonEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                v.clearFocus();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeuteEinladen.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, Details);
            });
            }
        }
    });
```

The Activity I start works perfectly fine, so this can't be se reason. When I tried the same with a normal Button and an onClickListener there was no Problem.
I also tried it with an onClickListener on the EditText, but this doesn't work either.
Now I worked out, that the Problem always appears, when I start the Activity (with the click on the EditText) close it so i come back to the Acitivity with the EditTexts and want to click another EditText with an onFocusChangeListener
What do I have to do, to avoid this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is the activity that has `setOnFocusChangeListener` is `LeuteEinladen` ?!

Comment: No, LeuteEinladen is another Activity without any setOnFocusChangeListener

Comment: I too have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity call onfocuschange method automatically at first time when you launch first time beacause it receive onfocus at that time,your logcat displaying stackoverflow error,it means your activity have not other control to receive onfocus,so it says stackoverflow

Comment: But I can open the Activity normally, without any error. Only if I hit an EditText wich opens another Activity, come back, and hit another EditText it says StackOverlfow